# setInternet2 cannot connect windows

Tags: windows, r, internet-explorer-8, installation

At work I usually have to set the `setInternet2(use=TRUE)` option in order to access cran for updating packages etc.. However after they updated win explorer to version 8 this doesnt seem to work anylonger. This is the output after trying to install e1071 both with and without the setInternet2 option invoked.

Any ideas if this can be remedied?

```
> install.packages("e1071")
Installing package(s) into ‘P:/R prg/R-2.13.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk' on port 80.
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk' on port 80.
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/windows/contrib/2.13
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'www.stats.ox.ac.uk' on port 80.
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to connect to 'www.stats.ox.ac.uk' on port 80.
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.13
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘e1071’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)

> setInternet2(use=TRUE)
> install.packages("e1071")
Installing package(s) into ‘P:/R prg/R-2.13.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/windows/contrib/2.13
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.13

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘e1071’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

Comment: You could always download/install manually. Do you have broswer access to CRAN?

Comment: I ended up mirroring the cran packages to my usb and I´ll bring them to work tomorrow. The browser works quite allright even at work.

Comment: @Misha Are you sure that `setInternet2(TRUE)` is execute before any web access from R? I keep `utils::setInternet2(TRUE)` in first line of `R-2.13.0\etc\Rprofile.site`. And it works for me with IE8. Second thing: are they any problems when you open repository directory in IE?

Comment: @Marek: Yup-setInternet2(TRUE) is set at start up with no effect. I dont have any problems accessing the repositories directly using IE.

Answer (score 0):

Speak with your network admins.  Get them to check that IE8's connection settings are configured properly.  It's also possible that they are blocking some kinds of traffic whatever port is the default for IE8 to use at your workplace.

Comment: I guess they are blocking it somehow-however it is strange that I can access the same files using IE 8 wthout any prbs. Could it be that the .dll file that setInternet2 is using is blocked from view or something?