# Sourcing R script over HTTPS

Tags: r

Is there some way to source an R script from the web?

e.g. `source('http://github.com/project/R/file.r')`

Reason: I currently have a project that I'd like to make available for use but isn't ready to be packaged yet. So it would be great to give people a single file to source from the web (that will then source all the individual function files).

On closer inspection, the problem appears to be https. How would I source this file?

```
https://raw.github.com/hadley/stringr/master/R/c.r
```

Comment: Uhm... yes? Did you try to do this? What happened?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can, try running this R tutorial:

```
source("http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/tutorial.R")
```

([Source](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/index.html))

Https is only supported on Windows, when R is started with the `--internet2` command line option (see [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e)):

```
> source("https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zdBYP5Ft")
> test()
[1] "passed"
```

Without this option, or on linux, you will get the error "unsupported URL scheme". In that case resort to the solution suggested by *@ulidtko*, or:

Here is a way to do it using `RCurl`, which also supports https:

```
    library(RCurl)
    eval( expr = 
        parse( text = getURL("http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/tutorial.R",
                       ssl.verifypeer=FALSE) ))
```

(You can remove the `ssl.verifypeer` if the ssl certificate is valid)

Comment: What is your system and R version? I get "unsupported URI scheme" error.

Comment: Strange... I tried it with R 2.13.1 x64 and 2.13.2 x64 on Windows 7 x64. In console mode (R.exe) it does not work for both, in Rgui only for 2.13.1, and with 2.13.2 as console in RStudio it also works. I checked with (.packages()) and always only these 7 are loaded: "stats"/"graphics"/"grDevices"/"utils"/"datasets"/"methods"/"base"

Comment: Found the solution: if R is started with the option --internet2 sourcing from https works, see also [link](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e)

Comment: Short update: the option --internet2 is windows only. Sourcing from https under Linux does not work (tested), so you would need a solution like _ulidtko_ posted here.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to dig until you found the solution.  Could you update your answer to reflect what you found re: the `--internet2` option?

Answer (score 33):

You can use the source_url in the devtools library

```
library(devtools)
source_url('https://raw.github.com/hadley/stringr/master/R/c.r')
```

This is a wrapper for the RCurl method by @ROLO

Comment: devtools also handles gists really nicely in R:
devtools::source_gist('11326436')

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible and worked for me right away.

```
R> source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zdBYP5Ft")
R> test()
[1] "passed"
```

---

Regarding the HTTPS part, it isn't supported by internal R code. However, R can use external utilities like `wget` or `curl` to fetch https:// URLs. One will need to write additional code to be able to `source` the files.

Sample code might be like this:

```
wget.and.source <- function(url) {
  fname <- tempfile()
  download.file(url, fname, method="wget")
  source(fname)
  unlink(fname)
}
```

---

There is a Windows-only solution too: start R with **`--internet2`** commandline option. This will switch all the internet code in R to using IE, and consequently HTTPS will work.

Comment: Using the `wget` utility could also be done like this: `source(pipe(paste("wget -O -", URL)))` .

Answer (score 2):

## Windows:

If Internet Explorer is configured to access the web using your organization's proxy, you can direct R to use these IE settings instead of the default R settings.  This change can be made once by the following steps:

1. Save your work and close all R sessions you may have open.
2. Edit the following file.  (Note: Your exact path will differ based on your R installation)

   C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\etc\Rprofile.site

Open this "Rprofile.site" file in Notepad and add the following line on a new line at the end of the file:

```
utils::setInternet2(TRUE)
```

You may now open a new R session and retry your "source" command.

## Linux alikes:

Use G. Grothendieck's suggestion.  At the command prompt within R type:

```
source(pipe(paste("wget -O -", "https://github.com/enter/your/url/here.r")))
```

You may get an error saying:

```
cannot verify certificate - - - - Self-signed certificate encountered.
```

At this point it is up to you to decide whether you trust the person issuing the self-signed certificate and proceed or to stop.

If you decide to proceed, you can connect insecurely as follows:

```
source(pipe(paste("wget -O -", "https://github.com/enter/your/url.r", "--no-check-certificate")))
```

---

**For more details, see the following:**

See section **2.19**

- [CRAN R Documentation 2.19](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html)
- [wget documentation section 2.8 for "no-check-certificate"](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

Similar questions here:

- [Stackoverflow setInternet2 discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901928/setinternet2-cannot-connect-windows)
- [Stackoverflow Proxy configuration discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832560/how-do-i-tell-the-r-interpreter-how-to-use-the-proxy-server)

Comment: utils::setInternet2(TRUE) is now defunct

Answer (score 1):

The methods here were giving me the following error from github:

```
OpenSSL: error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

I used the following function to resolve it:

```
github.download = function(url) {
  fname <- tempfile()
  system(sprintf("curl -3 %s > %s", url, fname))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  return(fname)
}
source(github.download('http://github.com/project/R/file.r'))
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on windows:

```
library(RCurl)
# load functions and scripts from github ----------------------------
fn1 <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SanjitNarwekar/Advanced-R-Programming/master/fn_factorial_loop.R", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
eval(parse(text = fn1))
```