# How to extract content from facebook using R

Tags: facebook, r

I want to extract the facebook updates messages using R, but I'm having some trouble. I tried following the tutorials given in http://www.brocktibert.com/blog/2012/01/19/358/ but I am getting the following error

```
$error$type
[1] "OAuthException"  
$error$code
[1] 190
```

Is there another way to extract messages from facebook?

Comment: It would be helpful if you give some code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Facebook (by intent), and you did not provide example code, but this looks like an error with https:.

rcurl could do this (I am using it for similar stuff), and as

[Sourcing R script over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715723/sourcing-r-script-over-https)

notes, --internet2 could also help.

Dieter