# Calling R code from URL using "source": working in RStudio but not in R (RGui)

Tags: rstudio, rgui

I'm very new to R and confused with two different results from RGui and RStudio (Both are ver.3.1.1.)

For some reasons, I have to put my R codes (txt format) in my Dropbox public folder and call it using the "source" code such as:

> source("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12900679/help.txt")

However, it doesn't work with RGui but does work with RStudio.

Here are the returned results:

In RGui,

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : unsupported URL scheme

In RStudio,

[1] "Help me"

This is my first stackoverflow question and I hope my question makes sense to you.

Thanks in advance,

DJ

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't support sourcing of https URLs out of the box on Windows. You may need to have RGui start R with the `--internet2` flag. If that isn't easy for you, there are other workarounds; this answer probably has what you're looking for:

[Sourcing R script over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715723/sourcing-r-script-over-https)