# Error message when using easyPubMed package in R

Tags: r, text-mining, information-retrieval, text-analysis, pubmed

I am trying to use `easyPubMed` package in R to download content from `PubMed` in txt format. I am trying to run the following example:

```
dami_on_pubmed <- get_pubmed_ids("Damiano Fantini[AU]")
```

However, at this point I get the following error:

> Error in url(myPubmedURL, open = "rb") : https:// URLs are not supported

How to solve this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Weird. I cannot reproduce this error... `url` should support https:// URLs...

Comment: Works with me. `str(dami_on_pubmed)` gives me `List of 9`.

Comment: I found this. It might be useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715723/sourcing-r-script-over-https]. If you are working in Windows, maybe you need an extra parameter to allow https data download to work. Alternatively, are you sure you are not behind a firewall or something?

Comment: @DamianoFantini I'm using RGui.exe, R 3.41 on Windows 10. So I'm not sure whether that's the problem.

Comment: I use R version 3.2.4 on Linux 64-bit. Unfortunately, I still cannot sort it out. I followed the link provided by Damiano but I think the solution there is relevant only for Windows?

Comment: I use R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) on Ubuntu 64-bit. Can you open any other _https_ URL using `url`? What do you get if you execute `url("https://www.google.com", "rb")`?

Comment: I get exactly the same error: Error in url("https://www.google.com", "rb") : 
  https:// URLs are not supported. What could be the reason for this?